# Do javascript timers impact bandwidth

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance

I have a page that uses a few timers and ajax calls to make it dynamic ie if i change anything on my ipad the page updates on my laptop ..and it querys a database and updates...

will this have an impact on my bandwidth because it constantly updates? anything to be worried about?

Comment: Each request and response consumes your bandwidth whether its sync or async. However bandwith consumption is directly proportional to data tranferred. If sent data is small it wont impact much

Comment: Depends on the size of the messages being sent back and forth, and how often they happen. Its quite easy to measure though, just monitor the requests using any browser console for a short while and do some math.

Answer (score 3):

Each AJAX call will create a connection to the server (unless an existing keep-alive connection is re-used) and send a HTTP request. This is extremely small though so it will not affect your network performance in a noticeable way.

However, for this kind of real-time notification polling is a bad idea. All somewhat modern browsers support WebSockets nowadays which use one persistent connection to transmit data.

Comment: You can also avoid polling the server by having requests that wait on the server side until a value changes, or a certain time elapses (say 10 seconds), the server then responds with the changes (or lack thereof), the browser updates, and immediately sends another request. I think there is a name for this architecture, but it eludes me.

Comment: "Long polling" - which is really just a workaround when you cannot use a proper solution like WebSockets.

Comment: That'd be it. Turns out there's a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) discussing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a few timers and AJAX calls **will impact the bandwidth**, more so if you're on an iPad / iPhone somewhere using your prepaid Internet minutes on a SIM card etc.

The *amount of impact* it will create is, however dependent on the frequency and the actual response. You have the following options to make it as painless as possible (bandwidth-wise):

1. ***minimize the AJAX response size*** - make it as small as possible if nothing changes, ideally completely empty
2. ***stop making AJAX calls when application is in the background*** - on IOS, it's possible to tell when the app is on a background, so if you don't need visual updates at that time but the app is still running, simply stop requesting them.
3. if you **do need to be notified with the app on background**, you are best to use Push notifications (as the app can get killed, paused, suspended while in the background)
4. as [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18980760/467164) in the previous comments, you can use ***[long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)*** to replicate Push notifications as well

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: P.S.: if you want to be really clever about this, you can use Push notifications even when the app is in front to actually only request updatea when something on the server changes - that, however needs a bit of architectural tinkering